# Injecting Router during unit tests (rc.5, Router 3.0.0-rc.1)

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, angular2-routing

I'm trying to unit test a component that uses the Router, my code is in typescript. There are numerous recipies for injecting Router in a test spec, but none work for me, and some are not usable in the current version. I tried this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([
    MyComponent,
    provideRouter([]),
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' }),
    provide(ActivatedRoute, { useValue: {} })
  ]);
});
```

and got the error message

```
Error: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router.
```

When I try to mock the Router altogether:

```
class MockRouter {
  public navigate() {}
}

beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([
    MyComponent,
    provide(Router, { useClass: MockRouter })
  ]);
});
```

the test suite stops altogether with the error message

```
TypeError: Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property.
```

In router_testing_module.d.ts, they suggest this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   configureModule({
     modules: [RouterTestingModule],
     providers: [provideRoutes(
         [{path: '', component: BlankCmp}, {path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp}])]
   });
 });
```

But the function `configureModule` does not seem to exist (yet? anymore?).

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: configureTestingModule should be TestBed.configureTestingModule